# Storing orders with different product types, each having a unique set of parameters, in MySQL

Tags: mysql, shopping-cart

I am working on an e-commerce website that will sell cloths but also provide a way to book a service, like manicure. I am trying to create a single shopping cart, to which users will add both. The user should have a single shopping cart and a single total to pay for in the end. The problem is how should I store these in the database?

Cloths will have size and colour as params, while the services will have the date and time, when the user wants to get the service. Storing all these parameters in a single table `order_items` doesn't look too wise, while storing params as a serialized string doesn't feel any better.

What is the most common way of storing this data together?

Comment: I believe the most common way would be to have a single table for the user, perhaps even another table with user_prefs and link those with IDs (keys) to order_items, order_services etc. Basically a seperate table for each seperate list of data (services, items, users etc. etc). Just link them with key IDs (eg. FK)   You can get some general tips at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also work for a e-commerce store and we ahd the same problem. Easiest is have a "cart" and "cart_item" table respectively, where the shared columns between the products are stored, eg: price, quantity etc.

Then you have a table "cart_item_voucher" and "cart_item_product" which save the details specific to the voucher or product. Each one will reference "cart_item" with the "cart_item_id" foreign key.

Also "cart_item" will have a type field and from there you can distinguish the difference.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your insight. This looks like a good, proper solution, which allows for getting all sorts of reports to be generated as well as applying discounts to individual items or the whole order, and so on. Are there any cons to this method?

Comment: Cons are minor, but the one that bugs me the most is that you code a bit extra to handle both, but you would do that any how. The other one is as soon as you start getting a lot of data queries get slow, just make sure your "big" queries are optimised.

Comment: I was also wondering, if there is a point in storing only unique items in the `cart_item_product` table. For example, if we store only a size and colour parameters for a product, should we keep creating a new row whenever a new green M-size shirt is added to a cart, thus generating a new ID, or store it once and retrieve the same ID for every further order? This way we could reduce the number of records stored for some cart items.

Comment: Well is the attribute specific to a voucher or product? if it isn't add it to the cart_item, if it is add it to cart_item_product. Also work with quantities, but specific to product attribute, eg: Large blue shoe != Blue shoe medium. Save the attribute to the the relevant table, so if the attribute is specific to all items (vouchers and products) save it to the cart_item table else if it is specific to either voucher or product save it there.

Comment: If you message me your email I will be so kind to give you an example ERD with a brief explanation.

Comment: I think I understand the structure that you are proposing, I am just trying to clarify the details on actual records that will be stored in `cart_item_voucher` and `cart_item_product` tables. Like I said before, if one user tries to buy a green M-size shirt, the new record with fields size = "M" and colour = "green" in `cart_item_product` gets an ID of 10. Then, when the next user wants exactly the same shirt ("M" and "green"), do you store it as a new record in the `cart_item_product` table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30474/discussion-between-we0-and-parrker9)